# Pointwise and uniform convergence of ($f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{e^{xn}}$)

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I would like to know if the sequence $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{e^{xn}}$ converges pointwise and uniformly. $f_{n}:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I think it is easier to show that it converges pointwise, because if we take the interval $\tilde{x}=[0,1]$ and assume that if $n \rightarrow \infty$, we would have that $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{e^{\tilde{x}n}} \rightarrow 0$. Nevertheless, when it comes to uniform convergence, may I say that $ \sup|f_{n}(x)-0|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\frac{1}{e^{xn}}|=\frac{1}{e^{n}}$?

My point is that this function does not converge uniformly, because in the interval $[0,1]$ we would have $f_{n}(0)=1$ and $f_{n}(1)=\frac{1}{e^n}$.

Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: The question makes no sense, since you don't tell us what is the domain of the $f_n$'s.

Comment: Sorry, José. I have just edited it.

Comment: Are you sure $f_n(0)\to 0$? What is $\tilde x$ exactly? When considering uniform convergence you have to take the limit as $n\to +\infty$ of that $\sup$. The point is that the pointwise limit function is discontinuous on $x\geq 0$ whereas the sequence consists of continuous functions. Hence, if the convergence was uniform the limit function would be continuous as well.

Comment: The convergence is not uniform because the limit function is not continuous.

Comment: @Gary, $\tilde{x}$ is an interval that I picked for the proof. I understood your point about the discontinuity around zero. Thus, we would have two limits depending on the value of $x$?

Comment: $|f_n(\frac 1 n)-f(\frac 1 n)|=\frac  1e$ which also shows that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @MateusMaciel If $\tilde x$ is the interval, what is the meaning of $\frac{1}{{e^{\tilde xn} }}$?

Comment: The value of $x$ varies between 0 and 1. I wanted to evaluate the function in a given interval, @Gary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in\Bbb R$, you have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=0\\0&\text{ if }x\in(0,\infty).\end{cases}$$Since $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function and since each $f_n$ is continuous, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you, José@